# Did Yugi duel against a prerecorded Pegasus or the real one?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

In the [duel between Yugi](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Yugi_and_Maximillion_J._Pegasus%27_TV_Duel_(manga)) and Pegasus using the [videotape](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Pegasus%27_videotape), supposedly every Pegasus move was pre-recorded before the fight; during the first half of the duel, Pegasus used subliminal messaging by inserting images into some frames to make Yugi choose certain types of monsters, so Pegasus theoretically would play the correct card to defeat him every turn. However we also know this is a [Shadow Game](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Game), so Pegasus could use supernatural effects instead of just manipulating Yugi using the frames or predict his moves due to his knowledge of the game and Yugi's strategies. So he (or his recording) can in theory use his [Millennium Eye](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Eye). According to the [wiki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Yugi_and_Maximillion_J._Pegasus%27_TV_Duel_(manga)), that was what happened:

> Secretly Pegasus was using his Millennium Eye to read Yugi's mind.

However, the timing of Yugi's turn durations and Pegasus turn durations seems to be too synchronized to be a duel against a pre-recorded tape. On the other hand, if it's *not* a pre-recorded tape, then how Pegasus would be prepared to duel Yugi in the exact day and hour he watches it? It would be ridiculous to think about the long-haired businessman waiting all the time until Yugi put the tape in his video. But the [wiki article](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Pegasus%27_videotape) suggests that the tape is more than a simple tape, allowing instant communication between the one in the tape:

> Although it appeared to contain a prerecording, **people on the tape were able to communicate with people watching as if they were present at the same time and location as them**.

I can't find in the manga a definite clarification if the duel was against a pre-recorded Pegasus or the real Pegasus in the same time, being able to communicate due to his Millennium Item effects over the tape. Is there any official explanation, be it in the manga or another source, about what really happened in this duel?

Comment: i havn't seen the episode in a long time but if i recall Pegasus used his eye when one of Yugi's friends questions dueling against a video, that was when the Shadow Game began and they started their duel. i have no proper citation for this but consider that it appeared that time did not pass outside the Shadow Realm in this duel so it may have been possible when the Shadow Game began Pegasus was drawn into the Shadow Realm and since time did not pass he could have been in a business meeting and no one would be any wiser

Comment: Hmmmmm, maybe it is a possibility... probably the explanation, if any, is "Shadow Game magic - best way to solve every plothole" ...

Answer (score 0):

It was the real Pegasus, because later in the show, Pegasus and Yugi are in the same place they were in during the beginning of the show. I know that because the background was the same as the beginning scene.

Comment: So, you are saying that after the video tape duel there was a scene in the anime where the real Pegasus appears in the same background he was during the tape? I'll try to rewatch the episode then to see that